# Xamarin Forms get the hours of the phone

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am a novice in Xamarin.

I am looking for a way to get the local date time of my phone in hours in order to compare it with 19h00 or 7:00pm depending on the country

Here is my code but it is not okey:

```
// Handle when your app starts
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();
DateTime hour_only = dt.Hour; 
if (hour_only = "19:00") 
{
    Debug.WriteLine("it time "); 
}
```

If there is a  better example I will take ,

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property `Hour` of a `DateTime` is an `int` type that represents the actual hour in 24 hours format.

As you can see in the [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.datetime.hour(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public int Hour { get; }
```

> Property Value
>
> Type: System.Int32
>
> The hour component, expressed as a value between 0 and 23.

So if you want to compare the actual hour with 7PM, you have to use the following code:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();

int hour_only = dt.Hour;

if (hour_only == 19) {

    Debug.WriteLine("it time ");

}
```

Be careful that use two `==` symbols to make a comparation, you were using only one:

`if (hour_only = "19:00") {`

Comment: Thanks very muh , just if I want to compare it with 7pm or 19:00 depending on country , the code remains the same?

Comment: Yes, 7PM and 19:00 in the 24 hours format is always 19